# What is the difference between die() and exit()?

Tags: php

I know PHP two function die(); and exit();
I am using both function when I want to stop everything.
These two functions are doing the same thing?
Can I only use one of them?

Comment: They're equivalent, as stated explicitly in the documentation. However, I would _strongly_ advise to only use them on 'success' conditions, not on errors. If you want to stop on an error, use a `trigger_error("Tell me what actually went wrong". E_USER_ERROR);` (which would help serveradmins find those in the logs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference - they are the same.

PHP Manual for [`exit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> Note: This language construct is equivalent to [`die()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php).

PHP Manual for [`die`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php):

> This language construct is equivalent to [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Comment: I personally use die() because it sounds more extreme.

Comment: :D I will use only die(); function

Comment: This is the way to go. Now if only PHP had a kill() function for extra brutality!

Comment: Does the kill(); function is more safe then die(); or exit(); ?

Comment: There's no kill() function. @Andrew just said if PHP had that function